# Pasar a otra activity mediante un botón dependiendo de la opción escogida en un Spinner

Tags: android

Mi  proyecto se trata de un programa que busque los profesores tiempo completo de cada facultad de la Universidad, en la primera activity tengo un Spinner con todas las facultades de la U y debajo hay un botón BUSCAR lo que quiero es que cuando escoga un opción en el Spinner por ejm Ciencias Y Tecnologías y le de click al  boton BUSCAR me lleva a otra activity que es sobre la facultad.

private Spinner Facultades;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Facultades = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp1);

    String [] OPfacultades = {"Ciencias y tecnologia", "Civil", "Electrica", "Industrial", "Mecanica","Sistema"};

    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, OPfacultades);
    Facultades.setAdapter(adapter);


}//Finaliza el onCreate
//Boton en pantalla de inicio
public void BuscarFacultades(View view) {
    String SeleccionF = Facultades.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if (SeleccionF.equals("Ciencias y tecnologia")) {
        Intent buscarCT = new Intent(this, CienciasYTecnologia.class);
        startActivity(buscarCT);
    }
}
```

Cuando lo intente correr salio todo bien, escogi la facultad en el spinner pero cuando le di click al boton no pasa nada.

Comment: Hola! Creo que no le estas asignando el ese método "BuscarFacultades"a tu botón o Lo estas asignando mediante el layout? Si es así. Podrías imprimir cual es el valor de "SeleccionF".

Comment: Hola bueno ayer casualmente después de escribir este post me di cuenta de algo que pensé que se ponía automáticamente, en la parte de desing de este main en el botón de "BUSCAR" en la opción onClick no había nada así que le di click y me salio el  método "BuscarFacultades" creo que tal vez podía ser por eso.

Comment: Si a lo mejor fue eso, no llamaba al método porque no lo tenia asignando. (y)

Comment: Gracias por responder, veré si se soluciono.

Comment: fui a ejecutar compilo y todo pero en el celular me sale "aplicacion se ha detenido"

Comment: Recuerda validar que los objetos no sean NULL.

Answer (score 0):

según veo el código no esta mal..

quizás no estés asignando correctamente el nombre del evento onclic a tu botón

toma como referencia esto.

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnBuscarFacultades"
                android:onClick="BuscarFacultades"
                android:text="boton valida" />
```